# Haskell: Extract Int from POSIXTime / NominalDiffTime

Tags: haskell, type-conversion, epoch

I am signing web requests, and as part of the query string, I need to include
`oauth_timestamp=123456789` where the `123456789` is the nominal time since 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC.

I have been using [POSIXTime](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.6/docs/Data-Time-Clock-POSIX.html) for its representation, which is just a type alias for [NominalDiffTime](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.6/docs/Data-Time-Clock.html#t:NominalDiffTime).

I am having problems when I want to convert the POSIXTime / NominalDiffTime to Text so that I can add it to the query string items collection.

The problem stems from the fact that the constructor for NominalDiffTime is private, and so I cannot extract the actual number.

Even the hacky way of using `show` will append an "s" generating `123456789s`.

Is there a simple way of extracting the actual number from the NominalDiffTime?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This might qualify as an example of typeclasses making APIs more esoteric than they have to be: `NominalDiffTime` implements `RealFrac`, the typeclass of arbitrary-precision fractions. As a result, the `floor` function is available to you:

```
λ> import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX
λ> pt <- getPOSIXTime
λ> pt
1458787669.804632s
λ> toRational pt
182348458725579 % 125000
λ> floor pt :: Int
1458787669
```